# Can "perpetration" be done in "a positive manner"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a definition of the word "commitment" on [Wiktionary.com](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/commitment) which was:

> Perpetration, in a negative manner, as in a crime or mistake.

I want to ask why the writer is emphasising the "negative" aspect of it. Is it because they want to mark it different from "an inadvertent manner" not "a positive manner"?

Comment: What you've linked is the definition of the word "commitment", not "perpetration". Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski- Sorry for that. I've edited the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first meaning of perpetrate is:

1. transitive. In a neutral sense: to carry out or carry on (an action); to perform. Also occasionally intransitive.

These definitions are from the OED, which is behind a paywall.

Sample OED sentence: 
1989   C. S. Murray Crosstown Traffic vii. 155   Sun rockabilly, as perpetrated by Presley, Lewis, Carl Perkins and assorted others.

**So, although many think this is just about crime, it is not.**

You could say: They perpetrated acts of kindness all around themselves.

Only the second meaning is negative:

2. transitive. To commit (a criminal, immoral, or harmful act). Also in weakened use: to commit (a folly, error, etc.).

Comment: That is very insightful but I want to ask can it be the case that the writer thinking that it would be better to clarify with "in a negative manner" so as to distinguish it from "an inadvertent manner"?

Comment: I provided a sentence with the positive meaning. I have answered your question already. Inadvertence (not on purpose)  is a separate thing.

Comment: I looked up "perpetrate acts of kindness" on Google and found about a half dozen hits. I looked "perpetrate acts of violence" on Google and found scores of hits. While I would agree that "perpetrate" can occasionally be used in a positive or neutral tone, I think it's overwhelmingly used in the negative, so much so that many dictionaries (like [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/perpetrate#perpetrate_4)) just include that as part of their definition.

Comment: Normally it's *paywall*, but I guess *firewall* works in a figurative sense. Oddly enough, the first definition (the neutral one) is labeled as obsolete in the second edition of the OED (published in 1989): "† b. in neutral sense. Obs. rare.", so I think this word may have been enjoying a revival of some sort, though a slight one. (In my non-native opinion, it's probably poetae exercising their licentias.)

Comment: Yes, yes,yes, we all know it is usually negative. So what? Yeah, paywall, that was a lapsus.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael Harvey, and have only found support for perpetration used in the derogatory. Lambie (comment below, separate answer on this page) mentioned that OED has a non-derogatory definition, and links to a book in which "perpetrate" is used non-derogatorily. But I think this definition of the word "commitment" could be incorrect for the following reasons:

- As you correctly point out, the definition is internally inconsistent because it clarifies "in a negative manner" despite that perpetration is always a negative act. Definitions are usually internally consistent. Thjs may be a minor point.
- As a native English speaker, I am not aware that "commitment" has this meaning. I'm not saying it's wrong, but I'm aware of all the other definitions, just not this one. This also may be a may be a minor point, since I don't know everything about the English language.
- I don't see any reference for this meaning on the Wiktionary page you linked to.
- [Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commitment) lacks this definition.
- [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/commitment) also lacks this definition.

I'd like to read what others have to say about this, but I can't confirm that this is a correct definition.

Comment: mRotten - "I am not aware that "commitment" has this meaning.". I am not either. I would use "commission" in e.g. the commission of a crime. To your dictionaries lacking the "perpetration" or "carrying out of an act" meaning, I can add Cambridge. – Michael Harvey 5 mins ago     Delete

Comment: perpetration is **not always bad**. The Oxford English Dictionary does not confirm this. We are just used to hearing it with regard to crime, that's all. https://books.google.com/books?id=1ZlJby9bBFcC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=%22perpetrate+goodness%22&source=bl&ots=o-tzXEvBE8&sig=ACfU3U1X2KCpcQtbbf99jKdA71xbaxPh7A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik9bvMpIDkAhVCTd8KHe5kDIwQ6AEwA3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22perpetrate%20goodness%22&f=false